# Topology subspace

Tags: general-topology

Suppose that $(f_{i})_{i\in I}$,$f_{i}:X\rightarrow X_{i}$ family of continuous functions and $f_{i}$ separates the points of X.Can we assume that X is a subspace of $\prod_{i\in I}X_{i}$ in terms of topology??

I read that if there is a continuous embedding $e:X\rightarrow \prod_{i\in I}X_{i}$ we can assume it.Is this statement true ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separating points is not enough, you need to separate points and closed sets as well. In that last case, the diagonal product of the $f_i$ from $X$ into the product (i.e. the map $e: x \to (f_i(x))_{i \in I}$) is an embedding from $X$ into $\prod_{i \in I} X_i$, and we can see $X$ topologically as a subspace of this product, as this means that $e[X]$ as a subspace is homeomorphic to $X$.

Comment: Yeah of course you are right , because there is a homeomorphism between X and e[X] , so they will share the same topology properties and e[X] is a subspace of product .Also you mentioned that we need separation between closed sets and points in order to prove that e is an embedding right ??

Comment: @Jonathan1234 indeed this is necessary and sufficient.

Comment: In  $Genera$l $Topology$  by R. Engelking,  this is called the Diagonal Theorem, and is used frequently.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet it’s a very useful theorem indeed.